# <hr> does not align center in chrome but works fine in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to align my `<hr>` tag to center and it works fine in IE and in Firefox but for some reason it does not work in Chrome. In Chrome the `<hr>` tag aligns to the left. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
html body {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

hr {
    border: 0;
    background:#F87431; 
    height:7px;
    clear:both;
    display: block;
    width: 96%;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 
}
```

Comment: I checked your code. and its working for me on Chrome. is it coz you forgot give value to `margin-right` in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try margin: auto in your hr style

```
hr {
    border: 0;
    background:#F87431; 
    height:7px;
    clear:both;
    display: block;
    width: 96%;
    background-color:black;
    margin: auto;
}
```

It work when i test by jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

it often works to add margin:0 auto to it.
that means that the margin to the top and bottom is 0, but to the sides it's auto, which makes it horizontally centered.